# Integral representations of $J_0(\sqrt{ x y})$ and $I_0( \sqrt{x y})$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

It can be shown that

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\rho  u-\frac{v}{\rho }}}{2\rho } \, d\rho=K_0(2\sqrt{uv})
\end{align}
$$
for $u,v>0$. Now, I wish to have a similar integral expression for $I_0(\sqrt{u v})$ (and, or, $J_0(\sqrt{u v})$), however $I_0(x)$ (and therefore $J_0(x)$) cannot be expressed in terms of $K_0(x)$, so I cannot transform the previous integral to this end. The question is then, are there constants $a$ and $b$ (maybe complex) and a function $C(\rho)$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty } C(\rho)\:e^{a\rho  u+b\frac{v}{\rho }} \, d\rho=I_0(2\sqrt{uv})
\end{align}
$$

$ab=1$ since $\partial^2I_0(2\sqrt{uv})/\partial u\partial v=I_0(2\sqrt{uv})$, but finding $C(\rho)$ is not that evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $\nu=0$, $z=2\sqrt{uv}$ and $t = u\rho$ in *Schläfli's integral* http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E19 yields
$$
J_0 (2\sqrt {uv} ) = \frac{1}{{\pi i}}\int_{ - \infty }^{(0 + )} {\frac{{e^{\rho u  - \frac{v}{\rho }} }}{{2\rho }}d\rho } .
$$
In this case you are forced to integrate on a loop contour in the complex plane. Similarly, taking $\nu=0$, $z=2\sqrt{uv}$ and $e^t  = \sqrt {u/v} \rho$ in http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E12 gives
$$
I_0 (2\sqrt {uv} ) = \frac{1}{{\pi i}}\int_{ - \infty }^{(0 + )} {\frac{{e^{\rho u + \frac{v}{\rho }} }}{{2\rho }}d\rho } .
$$
Let me add that your claim that $J_0$ cannot be expressed in terms of $K_0$ is not true, cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27.E9.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure, along which contour(s) are we integrating ? From the notation it  looks like just the real axis.

Comment: It is a simple loop contour that encircles the negative real axis in the positive sense. See https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.F1.mag